# R Code on Windows IoT Core 10

Tags: r, powershell, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I want to run R Code on Windows IoT Core 10, is there any possibility for this?

- I have tried to upload the R installation directory from my local PC to the Windows IoT core 10 device (Raspberry Pi 3)
- Then from Power Shell I am executing following command Rscript.exe testscript.R but I get following error

  Program 'Rscript.exe' failed to run: The operation completed successfully.

  - CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Is it possible at all to run R-Code on Windows IoT 10 core?

Any help is appreciated please.

**EDIT :**

I tried it from native command prompt on Windows IoT Core 10, and it gives error `"The system cannot execute the specified program."` So it looks like that it is not supported? Any suggestion/possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in this [Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/10/hello-windows-10-iot-core/) there is just support for languages like:

- C++
- C#
- JS
- VB
- Node.js and Python

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile R completely for ARM  or you can use Raspbian, its better than recompiling code anyway.